# Want to check if text is italic or not and if yes then highlight the text in textbox

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to retrieve the content that I am **copying from PDF** and pasting in the textbox

```
<textarea id="ta" onpaste="functionItalic(event)"></textarea>
```

the function getData(text/html') retrieves the data in the html/rich text format. I am storing the content in a variable.

```
function functionItalic(pasteEvent)
{
    var textareacont = (pasteEvent.originalEvent || pasteEvent).clipboardData.getData("text/html");
    console.log(textareacont);
}
```

on pasting the content of the PDF in textbox the text **on the console** is

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style>
<!--
br
{
mso-data-placement:same-cell;
}
table
{
mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\, ";
}
tr
{
mso-height-source:auto;
mso-ruby-visibility:none;
}
td
{
border:.5pt solid windowtext;
}
.NormalTable{cellspacing:0;cellpadding:10;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-layout-alt:fixed;border:none; mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .75pt;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; mso-border-insideh:.75pt solid windowtext;mso-border-insidev:.75pt solid windowtext}
.fontstyle0
{
    font-family:Times-Italic;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
-->
</style></head><body>
<!--StartFragment-->
<span class="fontstyle0">H</span> 
<br style=" font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; ">
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

This Style class is commmon for all **italic** texts

```
.fontstyle0
{
    font-family:Times-Italic;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Now I want to get all the words pasted in textbox that are italic and **highlight the italic words** in the **textbox**.

How can I do that using JavaScript.
Note: textarea stores the content in String format so variable **textareacont** is in **String**
Please help I am stuck and I know only beginner level JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight words using CSS, if you know the class of their containers.

Try something like this:

```
.fontstyle0
{
    background-color: yellow;
    font-family:Times-Italic;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: that class .fontsytl0 is class that is coming from the PDF rich text. I can not do something to that however all classes contain font-style: italic if the word is italic in PDF. And even if I add the background-color to the class wherever font-style:italic comes even then it will not get highlighted in the same textbox. Do you know any solution